# Getting error "C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I want to run Watir test from Eclipse.I have installed Ruby22 VM and also i have installed Watir Web Driver.In eclipse i have created ruby project with the standard Vm as Ruby22-X64.But when i run the test from eclipse it displays the above error.

But when i entered irb from command prompt and then if I enter require "watir-webdriver"it returns the message as True and it works fine.

Earlier it was working fine.After i do the factory reset for my System i face this problem,

Comment: Please run in terminal:  `which ruby`, `echo $GEM_HOME` and copy what it outputs.